# Arithmetic operation of binary numbers - Is my answer correct?

Tags: arithmetic, binary

Does the arithmetic operation -

102 (base 10)- 39 (base 10), represented in 8-bit, when converted to binary have an overflow or underflow?

My Ans - It has no problem. I mean there is neither overflow nor underflow because 8- bit numbers can range from -127 to +127. The answer to the binary operation is +63 and so it is within the range. Hence there is no over flow or under flow. Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are entirely correct.

There would certainly be overflow if we were adding $39_{10}$ to $102_{10}$ in two's complement, since the *sum* exceeds $127$, which is the maximum positive base 10 value representable in two's complement. However, there is no problem whatsoever when *subtracting* $39_{10}$ from $102_{10}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was getting confused because in doing the arithmetic operation ( addition of a negative number 102+(-39), I had a 1 remaining (carry). I thought that was overflow. But thanks for verifying my answer. REally appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome! ;-)

Comment: If you're here, can you please explain what underflow is? A situation that could best describe underflow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's correct.....................................

Comment: Can you pls tell me one more thing - 
is 2's complement taken only for negative numbers?

Comment: I think you're asking if you can use the same method to convert a negative binary number to a positive one. The answer is yes.